# True fullscreen in SDL

Tags: c++, sdl, fullscreen

Using C++ with SDL for graphics, I was wondering about full screen usage. Using the SDL_FULLSCREEN flag when I call SDL_SetVideoMode works well to make it full screen, but if the chosen resolution is less than the system's resolution, there's a black border around everything. How can I make the image stretch to be truly full screen?

Comment: That's a property of your monitor or your graphics driver, not your application.

Comment: But every other full screen application is actually full screen; why is SDL different?

Comment: The SDL Doc say: "SDL will attempt to use a fullscreen mode. If a hardware resolution change is not possible (for whatever reason), the next higher resolution will be used and the display window centered on a black background." So maybe your card doesn't support it, or maybe the OGL driver if you are using it.

Try enumerating all the supported display modes and make sure that the one you are trying to use is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding SDL_SWSURFACE flag to SDL_SetVideoMode call.

Which operating system are you using?

Comment: I am using SDL_SWSURFACE|SDL_FULLSCREEN, although SDL_SWSURFACE is defined as 0, so it doesn't actually do anything other than be a note to yourself.

I'm using Ubuntu, but it's virtualboxed on Windows 7 (my networking won't work on Linux unless I encap it through Windows). I'm not sure if this issue is due to my weird setup. Does everyone else have SDL_FULLSCREEN work well for them? I'm totally fine with it being weird on a weird setup, as long as it'll work properly on the normal user machine.

Comment: How about SDL_HWSURFACE then? Although, virtual box does some funny tricks. Have you tried activating fullscreen mode in the VirtualBox itself, then rebooting and when VM comes back up in fullscreen from the very start, try running your application.

Comment: Hmm, I tried running it right after a reboot with both HW and SWSURFACE, but no dice. Given that everyone here indicates that proper full screen is supported feature, I'm assuming that this is a kink in my virtualbox setup, and is hopefully not indicative of any wrong SDL setup.

Comment: After spending forever trying to figure out cross-compiling, I successfully ported it to Windows 7, and full screen works right there. So, the guess that virtual box was playing funny seems to be right.

Comment: "switch to scale mode" in virtualbox